# How come so different while using same Tahoma font representing same snippet of code in SciTE and PHPDesigner?

Tags: fonts, editor, scite

How come so different while using same **Tahoma** font representing same snippet of code in **SciTE** and **PHPDesigner**? 
Here is a screenshot.
[Why so much difference?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgvDZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Why so much difference?

From what I can see in the provided pictures the answer to this question is:

- on the left side you see the mono-space font variant, where on the right side you see the proportional font variant
- the sizes of the font vary between the left and right side
- on the right side you see the italics font variant

This site ( [fontfeed.com: styles-weights-widths-it’s-all-in-the-type-family](http://fontfeed.com/archives/styles-weights-widths-it%E2%80%99s-all-in-the-type-family/) ) gives some insight into the subject of different variants of the "same" font.

In addition to the issue with fonts where it is even possible that the font with the same name looks different *(you can't prevent the case that someone creates a font and give it a name of another one - in other words you can't be 100% sure the font is the same except you use the same file from which the font is loaded)* further reason for differences in what you see are different settings for the syntax highlighting (in SciTe and PHPDesigner). Such settings are highly customizable, so you will witness  differences between users of the same editor even in case of same font used.

> **`To see it for yourself what it is all about play a bit around with settings related to fonts and to syntax highlighting in your text editor(s).`**

In addition to already mentioned causes of differences in how you see the same font displayed each modern operating system allows also to change how the fonts are rendered to the screen (choosing a method for antialiasing), but the differences in how a font is displayed caused by this are only small ones.

Comment: Sorry, I definitely want to upvote your answer but somehow my attempts to do so get rejected.

Comment: I suppose your need more reputation points for upvoting, but what you can probably do is to accept the answer what will give me and you some reputation points.